# JavaScript unittesting with Jest - how do I run my scripts in the browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I use Jest to unittest my JavaScript code. Or at least I'd really want to use Jest.

The problem is that Jest need me to use `module.exports` in order to use the function inside of the testfile. And that means I can't use my JavaScript in the browser.

The simple Jest test looks like this:

```
// divide.js
function divide(a, b) {

  return a / b;

}

module.exports = divide;
```

```
// divide.test.js
const divide = require('./divide');

test('divides 10 by 2 equal to 5', () => {

  expect(divide(10, 2)).toBe(5);

});
```

And it works fine. I run `test` in the CLI and everything is nice.

I realize that Jest is written with React in mind (hence every guide on Jest uses React) but it seems to make a lot of sense for testing with (vanilla) JavaScript.

I realize that `module.exports` and `require` are Node.js specific. But I can't figure how to handle them in a way so that I can use the functions in my browserrendered code.3

Until now I've been solving this problem by commenting out `module.exports` - and that for sure ain't a viable way.

So my question is: How do I get to use my divide.js both in the test and in the browser?

I can think of to ways to go here:
 - Switch the testsuite to something else
 - Figure out what tooling or setup I need to create something like a main.js from the files containing `module.exports` in a way so that it can be used in the browser

Comment: Do you actually want to see your tests run in a real browser or are you OK with running them in a headless browser on the server and satisfying your tests with assertions where you cannot see the render?

Comment: Okay. I'm in deep here.  So sorry in advance if I misunderstood your question.

I really like just typing 'test' in the CLI and then see the output from the tests there.

I have no need to run the test itself it in a browser. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand. You want to unit test "browser code" in your testing framework on the server without polluting your browser code with module.exports?

Comment: How do you currently get your divide.js file into the rest of your client side app?

Comment: Yes. Exactly :D

Comment: I use the good old 
`<script src="divide.js"></script>`

Comment: I believe you should invest a bit of time getting to know [ES6 Modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) which will work both in the browser and in node. Node is moving towards native ES6 modules [right now too](https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff). You can not make this work without using modules.

Comment: Side note - Using import syntax from ES6 modules should help you.

Comment: something like `export function divide(a,b) {}`? And then use Babel for backwards compatibility?